# how can i get group table name and also get am i member or not in that group

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a project, there has group feature. when I search any group, this time I have to know that am I already join those listed group.

I have group table and another table group user table for adding the user to the group.

I want to get it with SQL query only with one query. How can I do it?

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Place your effort code here, atleast give your tables with structure.

Comment: group table - gorup_id, group_name......    and user_group table user_group_id, group_id, user_id .....

Answer (score 0):

You could try an inner join

> SELECT *
>   FROM Groups
>   INNER JOIN UserGroup on Groups.Group_ID = UserGroup.Group_ID

I don't know exactly your tables,but it should be something like that.